# Javascript: Array Sort returns different result for Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, google-chrome, mozilla

Consider following data for testing the scenario.

When I use sort method on array with comparison function:

```
['a', 7, 65, '65'].sort((a,b) => a-b)
```

Output for Mozilla:

```
[ 7, 65, "65", "a" ]
```

Output for Chrome

```
["a", 7, 65, "65"]
```

The output seems to be different in both.
**Please focus on the reason why this happens rather than giving the solution on how to sort.**

The objective of this question is to understand why is there a different implementation of sorting when it compares `NaN` in different engines.

Example: `'a' - 65` will return `Nan`;

---

[Update]
Sorting `['a', 65].sort((a,b) => a-b)`

Chrome: `[65, 'a']`

Mozilla: `['a', 65]`

---

Sorting `[65, 'a'].sort((a,b) => a-b)`

Chrome: `['a', 65]`

Mozilla: `[65, 'a']`

Why does this behavior happen

Comment: That's intriguing

Comment: Try `['a', 7, 65, '65'].sort((a,b) => a - b || a > b)` to get rid of undefined string vs integer comparisons.

Comment: @WaisKamal that would return the wrong data type for the comparator

Comment: Seems to be implementation differences in how `.sort()` compares `NaN`

Comment: @Phil I didn't get you, how will it return the wrong type? If it is comparing two numbers, it will return a number. If it is comparing two strings, it will return a boolean.

Comment: Implementation of sorting seems to be same in chrome and safari but is different in Mozilla.
In this case its purely comparing of stable sorting of unicode numbers.

Comment: @WaisKamal a comparator should return an integer, never Boolean. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#description

Comment: Didn't know that before, but in this case you can just convert the boolean into a number: `['a', 7, 65, '65'].sort((a,b) => a - b || Number(a > b))`.

Comment: It's interesting, but we likely will not find the answer/cause here and probably shouldn't. As you say, a comparator should return an Integer. Returning NaN is asking for UB

Comment: `NaN` results don't have a precisely defined place. So you get a non-precisely defined place. Not a real big mystery.

Comment: @WaisKamal that will simply not work. You will only ever get `0` or `1` out of that which misses out on `-1` to indicate `b` comes before `a`

Comment: @WaisKamal [Sorting in JavaScript: Shouldn't returning a boolean be enough for a comparison function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24080785)

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Guys, you are going away from the actual question. :-D
Looking for a reason why that happens rather than the solution.

Comment: @Phil nevermind, use `Number(a > b) - 0.5` :)

Comment: "*Guys, you are going away from the actual question*" it's quite hard given that the question you posted contains no question. You've said there is a difference. There is a "*PS: Don't consider changing the return type in the function.*" but I don't see what it relates to. Your latest update was to add a C++ source code link for WebKit. As it stands, doesn't *ask* for anything specific.

Comment: @WaisKamal then you miss out on the equality (`0`) check. Just don't do it

Comment: ("a"-65) is NaN, it happens because of that. Some things in programming are just undefined and implementation dependend, be it in JavaScript, C, or other languages. If you violate the spec of comparator functions you are left with that.

Comment: @SantoshKumar Chrome and Firefox use different interpreters (V8 and Baseline(?) respectively) and it seems that each has a different implementation of `Array.sort`.

Comment: @VLAZ updated more info on that. 
Why I had added C++ code is to understand what's happening under the hood of webkit based engines. 

What I'm looking for is the reason why the sorting gives different solutions on different browser.

Comment: @Phil if two strings are equal, the order you put them in doesn't matter.

Comment: @WaisKamal But in the end, it's a stable sort AFAIK. Compare the unicode and return in ascending order. Which one is correct here? What is the reason for the change.

Comment: @SantoshKumar what is your question? You're telling behaviours are different in different browsers, and we've told you it happens because of the return type of `sort` in your implementation.

Comment: This is happening because Firefox uses SpiderMonkey and Chrome uses V8 as a JS engine, and the behaviour of NaN during sorting is not consistent across different engines.

Comment: @SantoshKumar the reason is simple - `NaN` result is not covered in the specs. So you get the behaviour that different people thought is appropriate. But there is no agreement of what "appropriate" is.

Comment: @AyushGupta Return type of sort? How does that affect sorting in Mozilla and chrome?

Comment: @SantoshKumar what is `"a" - 65`

Comment: @SantoshKumar refer to the link posted by VLAZ: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#description. *"Compare the unicode and return in ascending order."* do this in your sort function.

Comment: regarding you edit, and as Ayush suggested: I am pretty certain that Chrome is not using JavaScriptCore anymore but rather V8, so the source link is likely not relevant

Comment: @TobiasK. Yep, JSCore is the one Safari uses.

Comment: Voting for closure for _Needs details or clarity_ as this question doesn't ask any specific question.

Comment: Here's the [link](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.sort) to relevant ECMA spec. And I quote **The sort order is implementation-defined [...] if comparefn is not undefined and is not a consistent comparison function for the elements of items** . The spec explicitly allows implementation-defined behavior when the *comparefn* mal-behaves.

Comment: @SantoshKumar As per the spec, **both** engines' behaviors are correct. The reason is that you supply a bad comparison function as argument, it's not clear what your desired behavior should be, thus you leave it up to the engine to decide whatever they feel alright.

Comment: @hackape I agree with what you are saying. The confusion and the question which I have is that shouldn't the implementation of the sort be uniform across?
Even [https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/overview.html#implementation-defined](Spec) says that implementation of such can be different.

The actual question is about why there are differences in different browsers since its a simple sorting mechanism that happens.

Comment: @hackape also the compare function in my case is defined. Its just sorting happens in different way

Comment: @SantoshKumar in which order should `["hello", 500, {}]` be sorted and why according to your compare function?

Comment: @AyushGupta I have updated my question above. Read it again. It's more about why does the different engines have a different sorting mechanism. Do you need more clarification?

Comment: @SantoshKumar The ES spec does NOT define the behaviour when the compare function does not return `-1` `0` or `1`(or any other number). In that case, the browsers are free to sort however they want, and different browsers do it differently.

Comment: @SantoshKumar "*why there are differences in different browsers since its a simple sorting mechanism that happens*" it is *precisely* because it's a simple sorting mechanism. It's under-specified for this case. The comparison function should return positive, negative, or zero. Therefore, it's equipped to handle positive, negative or zero. `NaN` is neither, positive, nor negative, nor zero. Therefore, handling it should come as one of the other three behaviours. We can rule out zero, so it's one of two - positive or negative. Three browsers chose different things.

Comment: _why is there a different implementation of sorting when it compares NaN in different engines_ - because the spec does not define what the behaviour should be

Comment: And to be fair - it's good that the behaviour is different for different browsers for undefined cases like this - otherwise people would start relying on spec-undefined behaviour instead of doing this correctly.

Comment: @AyushGupta , VLAZ I got your point. Totally makes sense what you saying. I was trying to understand what sorting algorithm runs behind array.sort(comparfun).

Few years back most of the browsers have adopted to TimSort to make it efficient. Looks like sorting varies with browsers when its NaN.

Comment: @AyushGupta how is that good? If there is no consistent way of knowing what would happen in which browser.

Comment: @SantoshKumar yep, my point exactly. So now users are being forced to handle NaN in their logic return a numeric value for a defined behaviour, which is what comparefn SHOULD return as per the spec, thus promoting correct behaviour.

Comment: "*I was trying to understand what sorting algorithm runs behind array.sort(comparfun)*" then what you asked was [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Asking how `NaN` is handled in no way shape or form will reveal exactly the algorithm. In fact, browsers usually use different algorithms based on the input size - for very small arrays, they might use bubble sort and something with better complexity for large arrays. There is no guarantee about the algorithm between different inputs, browsers, or versions. `.sort()` is just a contract.